# glTexImage2d and GL_R8UI fails on some GPUs

Tags: c, winapi, opengl

I'm trying to use GL_R8UI to pass unsigned, unnormalized data to a shader, but have found that on at least one GPU it doesn't work.

ie: this works:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8, 32, 32, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pData);
```

but this doesn't:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8UI, 32, 32, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pData);
```

I'm also changing the shader to use sampler2D vs usampler2D and updating the math in the shader appropriately, but finding it works on AMD/Radeon cards but fails on Intel <strike>and NVidia</strike> cards - the usampler2D always seems to return zero.

I've put together a minimal [sample program here](https://bitbucket.org/toptensoftware/shadertest/src/master/ShaderTest/ShaderTest.cpp?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default). The `#define NORMALIZED` switches between the two approaches.

So... my main question is:  is this simply a driver problem or is there something else wrong in my code that's causing this?

---

To ask this question another way...  what else needs to be changed to switch from GL_R8 normalized data to GL_R8UI unnormalized data, besides:

1. changing the call to glTextImage2D
2. changing from sampler2D to usampler2D in the shader
3. changing the shader to work with uint's instead of floats
4. changing the math in the shader to deal with normalized vs unnormalized data.

---

I've now logged an bug report with Intel: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/graphics-driver-bug-reporting/topic/748843

---

Since it was asked for here's the full example program source:

```cpp
// ShaderTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ShaderTest.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <GL/gl3w.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")

#define NORMALIZED

const char* pszVertexShader = R"***(

#version 150

uniform mat4 transform;

attribute vec3 position;

varying vec2 vPosition;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = transform * vec4(position,1.);
    vPosition = position.xy;
}

)***";


#ifdef NORMALIZED

const char* pszFragmentShader = R"***(

#version 150

uniform sampler2D TextureData;

varying vec2 vPosition;

void main()
{
    float red = texelFetch(TextureData, ivec2(0, 0), 0).r;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(red , 0, 0, 1);
}

)***";

#else

const char* pszFragmentShader = R"***(

#version 150

uniform usampler2D TextureData;

varying vec2 vPosition;

void main()
{
    // Original post had this wrong
    // float red = float(texelFetch(TextureData, ivec2(0, 0), 0)).r/255.0;

    // Fixed version - still fails on Intel GPUs though
    float red = float(texelFetch(TextureData, ivec2(0, 0), 0).r)/255.0;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(red, 0, 0, 1);
}

)***";

#endif

int CompileShader(GLenum type, const char* pszSource)
{
    int iShader = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(iShader, 1, &pszSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(iShader);

    // Dump log
    int length;
    glGetShaderiv(iShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
    if (length != 0)
    {
        char* pszLog = (char*)_alloca((sizeof(char) + 10) * length);
        GLsizei len;
        glGetShaderInfoLog(iShader, length, &len, pszLog);
        OutputDebugStringA(pszLog);
    }

    // Check for error
    int status;
    glGetShaderiv(iShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == 0)
    {
        // Clean up after failuer
        glDeleteShader(iShader);
        return 0;
    }

    // Success
    return iShader;
}

// Globals
HINSTANCE hInst;
HGLRC g_hRC;
GLint g_iVertexShader = 0;
GLint g_iFragmentShader = 0;
GLint g_iShaderProgram = 0;
GLuint g_iTexture = 0;
GLuint g_iVertexBuffer = 0;

#define glCheck() assert(glGetError() == 0)

struct VERTEX
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

bool Setup()
{
    // Compile shaders
    g_iVertexShader = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, pszVertexShader);
    g_iFragmentShader = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, pszFragmentShader);

    // Link program
    g_iShaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(g_iShaderProgram, g_iVertexShader);
    glAttachShader(g_iShaderProgram, g_iFragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(g_iShaderProgram);

    // Dump log
    int length;
    glGetProgramiv(g_iShaderProgram, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
    if (length != 0)
    {
        char* pszLog = (char*)_alloca((sizeof(char) + 10) * length);
        GLsizei len;
        glGetProgramInfoLog(g_iShaderProgram, length, &len, pszLog);
        OutputDebugStringA(pszLog);
    }

    // Check for error
    int status;
    glGetProgramiv(g_iShaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == 0)
        return false;

    // Create texture
    glGenTextures(1, &g_iTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_iTexture);
    uint8_t* pData = (uint8_t*)_alloca(32 * 32 * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memset(pData, 128, 32 * 32 * sizeof(uint8_t));
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
#ifdef NORMALIZED
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8, 32, 32, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pData);
#else
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8UI, 32, 32, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pData);
#endif
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    // Create vertex buffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &g_iVertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_iVertexBuffer);
    VERTEX v[] = {
        { 10, 10, 0, },
        { 10, 230, 0, },
        { 310, 10, 0, },
        { 310, 230, 0, },
    };
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(v), v, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Done
    return true;
}

void Cleanup()
{
    if (g_iVertexBuffer)
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &g_iVertexBuffer);
    if (g_iTexture)
        glDeleteTextures(1, &g_iTexture);
    if (g_iShaderProgram)
        glDeleteProgram(g_iShaderProgram);
    if (g_iVertexShader)
        glDeleteShader(g_iVertexShader);
    if (g_iFragmentShader)
        glDeleteShader(g_iFragmentShader);
}

void Display(RECT* prc)
{
    // Setup viewport
    glViewport(0, 0, prc->right, prc->bottom);

    // Clear background
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0.5f, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Setup program
    glUseProgram(g_iShaderProgram);

    // Bind vertex buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_iVertexBuffer);

    // Setup vertex buffer
    int aPosition = glGetAttribLocation(g_iShaderProgram, "position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(aPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(VERTEX), 0);

    // Setup texture
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_iTexture);
    int uTextureData = glGetUniformLocation(g_iShaderProgram, "TextureData");
    glUniform1i(uTextureData, 0);

    // Setup ortho projection
    float left = 0;
    float right = 320;
    float top = 0;
    float bottom = 240;
    float fnear = -1;
    float ffar = 1;
    float proj[] = {
        (float)(2.0 / (right - left)), 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, (float)(2.0 / (top - bottom)), 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, (float)(-2.0 / (ffar - fnear)), 0.0f,
        (float)(-(right + left) / (right - left)), (float)(-(top + bottom) / (top - bottom)), (float)(-(ffar + fnear) / (ffar - fnear)), 1.0f
    };
    int uTransform = glGetUniformLocation(g_iShaderProgram, "transform");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uTransform, 1, false, proj);

    // Draw 
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    glFlush();
}

bool InitOpenGLContext(HWND hWnd)
{
    // Setup pixel format
    HDC hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(pfd));
    pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    int pf = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd);
    if (pf == 0 || !SetPixelFormat(hDC, pf, &pfd))
        return false;
    DescribePixelFormat(hDC, pf, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR), &pfd);
    g_hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);
    if (!g_hRC)
        return false;

    // Init gl3w
    wglMakeCurrent(hDC, g_hRC);
    int err = gl3wInit();
    if (err)
    {
        wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
        wglDeleteContext(g_hRC);
        g_hRC = NULL;
        return false;
    }

    // Setup
    if (!Setup())
    {
        assert(false);
        Cleanup();
        wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
        wglDeleteContext(g_hRC);
        g_hRC = NULL;
        return false;
    }

    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
    return true;
}

void CleanupOpenGLContext(HWND hWnd)
{
    HDC hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
    wglMakeCurrent(hDC, g_hRC);
    Cleanup();  
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
    wglDeleteContext(g_hRC);
}



LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            RECT rc;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            wglMakeCurrent(hdc, g_hRC);
            Display(&rc);
            wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        case WM_ERASEBKGND:
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register Class
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SHADERTEST));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"ShaderTest";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));
    RegisterClassExW(&wcex);

    // Create Window
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(L"ShaderTest", L"ShaderTest", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        50, 50, 100, 100, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
    if (!hWnd)
        return 7;

    RECT rc;
    rc.left = 0;
    rc.top = 0;
    rc.right = 320;
    rc.bottom = 240;
    AdjustWindowRect(&rc, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE), FALSE);

    SetWindowPos(hWnd, NULL, 0, 0, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

    if (!InitOpenGLContext(hWnd))
    { 
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        return 7;
    }

    // Show window
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // Main message loop:
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    CleanupOpenGLContext(hWnd);

    DestroyWindow(hWnd);

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

---

Comment: The problematic code has to be included **in the question itself**. Please read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on how to ask good questions.

Comment: I thought I had included the problematic code.  Changing that one quoted line causes it to fail - in one version the shader sees the texture data in the other it doesn't. I've described the incidental changes that follow on from this change (sampler2D to usample2D) and everything else is the same so to include all that would obfuscate the problem at hand. As far as I'm aware everything else is correct so I'm not sure what else I could include that would improve to the question.

Comment: I ask about the full code because you placed a link to an external source in your question. But this requires a registration at bitbucket which I'm not going to do. If you have to add links to external resources (which is suboptimal in the beginning because they could get deleted in the future), make at least sure that they can be accessed without having to register somewhere.

Comment: How does "doesn't work" manifest? What does break, specifically?

Comment: @BDL - sorry I didn't realize I hadn't marked the repo as public.  It should be accessible now.  I've also pasted a copy into the question.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz as mentioned in the question - "usampler2D always seems to return zero".

Comment: I'm not sure if this really works: `float(texelFetch(TextureData, ivec2(0, 0), 0)).r`. You are first casting a uvec4 to a float and then access it's r component. Could you try: `float(texelFetch(TextureData, ivec2(0, 0), 0).r)`?

Comment: @BDL - Well spotted! Just tried that and unfortunately it made no difference on Intel GPU.  I'm not near NVidia machine atm - I'll try it a bit later.

Comment: @BDL - it did fix it on NVidia though.  I'll update the question to reflect all this.

Answer (score 2):

Integer textures need to have nearest filtering (not linear or mipmap):

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```